# Matlab - convert number to zero when cumsum of previous data greater than a specific number

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with two columns.

Column one is a set of data consisting of 0 and 1.

Column tow is a set of time data on a daily basis.

Here is an example data below:

```
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-01
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-01
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-02
0 2020-01-02
...
```

I would like to set the following data to zero when cumsum of previous data within a day is greater than a specific number.

According to the example data, if the specific number is set to 2 then the data of 2020-01-01 is converted to the following data:

```
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-01
0 2020-01-01
0 2020-01-01
0 2020-01-01
0 2020-01-01
```

Here is how I can do it within a day:

```
for i = 1:7
    if cumsum(data(1:i,1) > 2)
      then data(i) = 0
    end
end
```

But I haven't figure out how to do it recursively.

**Recursively means when the data of next day will recalculate the sum and convert the following data to 0 when the sum is greater than a specific number.**

According to the example above:

```
    1 2020-01-01
    1 2020-01-01
    0 2020-01-01
    1 2020-01-02
    0 2020-01-02
    0 2020-01-02
    1 2020-01-02
    1 2020-01-02
    0 2020-01-02
    1 2020-01-02
    ...
```

The next day's data will be converted like this:

```
    0 2020-01-01
    1 2020-01-01
    1 2020-01-01
    0 2020-01-01
    0 2020-01-01
    0 2020-01-01
    0 2020-01-01
    1 2020-01-02
    0 2020-01-02
    0 2020-01-02
    1 2020-01-02
    0 2020-01-02
    0 2020-01-02
    0 2020-01-02
    ...
```

**You can see the data of two different day is handled seprately with a same process.**

I only know that I have to set the cumsum to zero and recalculate the cumsum when the date changed.

Is there any way to do it recursively?

Thanks a lot!

gastray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that recursion necessary in your case, simple matrix indexing will do it for you:

```
my_mat =

 0     8
 1     8
 1     8
 0     8
 1     8
 1     8
 0     8
 1     8
 0     8
```

let's take `my_mat` as your matrix, and manipulate it using indexing:

```
my_mat((cumsum(my_mat(:,1))>2),1) = 0
```

output:

```
my_mat =

 0     8
 1     8
 1     8
 0     8
 0     8
 0     8
 0     8
 0     8
 0     8
```

let's separate the command:

```
cumsum(my_mat(:,1))
```

yields a binary vector that is True when the condition is met and 0 otherwise,

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
```

now we can access only the relevant entries in the matrix by using this vector as the vector indexing.

Now if you want to take it the next step and change the value to 0 only if the second col is 8, we will improve the condition in the indexing vector like so:

```
my_mat((cumsum(my_mat(:,1))>2 & my_mat(:,2)==8))=0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But there is a problem when next day's data coming into consideration.
I would like to recalculate the sum within next day's data.
I have tested the code you provide and think about it for a while.
It cannot recalculate the sum everyday.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to `cumsum` only for the relevant date? if so, you can take one of 2 approaches => 1: calculate for the first date, then zero all the first col correlated to the date, then for the next date (`cumsum` 0's of the previous date -> ignore them), and so on. 2: `cumsum` only for the relevant date using indexing, e.g: `cumsum(my_mat(cumsum(my_mat(:,1))>2 & my_mat(:,2)==8,1)` i'm not in front of MATLAB so note sure that the pseudo code i just wrote is right, but just to give a direction. if something still don't work, you can comment again and i'll try it on MATLAB later on.

Comment: I have updated my question more clearly, thanks for your help again!

Comment: Thanks for your direction! I will try it on MATLAB and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner on MATALAB and I have tried some ways under your direction, but still can't solve the problem. 
I think it still need recursion because the process must work on everyday's data seperately.
I have updated my question more clearly, can you reread it and do some test on MATLAB? THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Thanks finally I have solved the problem by dividing the data by date.Then I can use your method in the answer seperately on every cell's data.

Comment: Great! You can also loop over the dates and apply this. (Of course that in general loops are less recommended but if the alternative is to sepperate so its the same)